# EntityManagerFactory is closed in Weblogic while deploying an ear

Tags: java, weblogic, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, weblogic12c

I have two separate ear files that use the same persistence unit defined in their persistence.xml. While deploying the second ear file in a Weblogic 12.2.1.3 I'm getting the following error:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
>           at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
>           at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
>           at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
>           at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
>           at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>           at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
>           at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>           at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>           at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>           at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

I cannot find any information about the life cycle of EntityManagerFactory in Weblogic. Why an EntityManagerFactory may be closed from weblogic. Could anyone give a hint about the problem or a link where I could find more information.

The ear files contain a standard JEE7 SOAP Web services that use JPA, JTA and eclipse link 2.5.2 as JPA engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle support refer that this is a bug that will be fixed in 12.2.1.4. Until then the patch 29154575 is only valuable if Weblogic version is 12.2.1.2.0.
As a workaround you can disable Parallel Deploy Application Module feature in config.xml file of Weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

This is weblogic bug.
See Doc ID 2502618.1 on Oracle support.

Suggested solutions from Oracle support:

As a solution apply patch 29154575
As a workaround:
Disable Parallel Deploy Application Module feature. Disabling this will ensure that various modules of application are activated sequentially avoiding the race condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just few clarifications. 1) This patch is designed for Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2.0 and cannot be applied in 12.2.1.3. The output is that it is not needed. But the problem still exist in 12.2.1.3. 2) When we set the <parallel-deploy-application-modules> attribute from true to false inside the config.xml everything is working fine. 3) Is it possible to alter this attribute from UI console of weblogic?

Comment: Patch 29154575 has a general classification, so I think it can be applied to weblogic 12.2.1.3 as well. Did you set the correct ORACLE_HOME in your shell before executing OPatch? I cannot see any domain level UI item to set ParallelDeployApplications in 12.2.1.3 console.